# Derivative as Approximation and little-o notation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Would this be correct:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable. So:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x  \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
Define $p(\Delta x )= |f'(x)  - \frac{f(x + \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}|$. Then for $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\Delta x >0$ such that:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x  \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} + p(\Delta x)$$
and $p(\Delta x) < \Delta x$. Then:
$$f(x + \Delta x) =f(x)+\Delta x f'(x) + (\Delta x) p(\Delta x)$$
and $\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} |\frac{(\Delta x)p(\Delta x) }{\Delta x}|=0$ meaning $\Delta x p(\Delta x) = o(\Delta x)$ and $f(x + \Delta x) =f(x)+\Delta x f'(x) + o(\Delta x)$.

In higher dimensions $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the existence of functions $f', p$ the definition of differentiability?

Comment: Broadly speaking yes, $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if for all $h\in\mathbb R^m$ we have $$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)(h)+\|h\|p(h)$$ (you need $p(0)=0$ and $p$ continuous at $0$ too). Here the derivative $f'(a):\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ is a linear map.

Comment: How do I ensure that $p$ satisfies these conditions?

Comment: Didn't you just define $p(\Delta x)$ to be the zero function? I think you meant to define something else. (Maybe without the limit.)

Comment: You are right I have fixed it.

Comment: Well, normally it's kinda clear that the error is $o(\|h\|)$. For example, let's check that $f(x)=\|x\|^2$ is differentiable. Expanding gives $$f(a+h)=\|a+h\|^2=f(a)+2\langle a,h\rangle+\|h\|^2.$$ So in this case $p(h)=h$ clearly satisfies the conditions, and the derivative at $a$ is the map $h\mapsto\langle a,h\rangle$.

Comment: Ok and does this only need to be checked in the multivariate case?

Comment: @gxyzv no, it applies in the single variable case too (but like I said is usually obvious).

Comment: Ok so I should explicitly set $p(0)=0$, and for continuity at $0$ this is clear because $p(\Delta x) \to 0$  as $\Delta x \to 0$.

Comment: However, I see no guarantee that $p$ is continuous for any interval around $0$, is that ok? However, I think I can choose to define $p$ such that it is continuous. As $\Delta x \to 0$ the difference may jump, but since the requirement is that $p(x) \Delta x = o(\Delta x )$ I can make $p$ continuous. Is that correct?